# How can I match the content between the first two slashes in an URL?

Tags: python, regex

I have an URL like this:

```
/selt/zvt/202/5/2000981
```

I just want to capture `/selt/`

How can I do this?

Comment: if the logic is always the same, then split is the better option here imo.

Comment: What have you done so far to try to solve this? Would `url[:6]` suffice?

Comment: @Sayse I tried something like this ```^[^/]*/``` but it only cat catches the first slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the string on "/" and take the element at index 1.

```
"/selt/zvt/202/5/2000981".split("/")[1]
```

**Edit:**

My previous answer would return "selt" and OP wants the "/" also.
You could use the previous code and manually add the "/" or you can match with regex:

```
import re
re.findall(r"^/\w+/", "/selt/zvt/202/5/2000981")[0]
```